# What is the difference between the switching speed and clock speed of a chip

Tags: transistors, power-electronics, switching, clock-speed

I learnt that the switching speed of Silicon-based devices are in the KHz range whereas that of III-V semiconductors like GaN are in the MHz range.
How does this differ from the clock speed that we hear about in CPU/GPUs?

Would appreciate it if I could be pointed to any good and easily accessible reading material. I googled it, but could not find an easy enough explanation.

Thank You

Comment: I don't know about you, but the silicon-based CPU runs in the GHz, and silicon-based transistors I build stuff with at work can switch in the MHz if I make them do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The maximum switching rate depends on many factors, but  based on your information, the rate is always limited by the load to each stage.

Thus an inductive to capacitive power storage and voltage converter must switch slower than a CPU smaller junctions and only a pF load between transistors.

Slew rate in logic tends to be faster as the driving current in CMOS is only a small capacitive load.  Making the gates switch at lower thresholds with smaller lithography and lower On resistance into a tiny capacitive load permits them to operate with less current and faster speeds.

Speed is always limited by the losses and heat rise from a switch resistance driving a capacitive load where rise time Tr=0.35/BW (-3dB) from 10 to 90%

Another way to look at a switch speed is the step rise time with the driver resistance Ron and C load where  T=Ron * C to 64% of the exponential curve which determines how fast it can switch.

e.g Thus a small low capacitance 25 ohm CMOS logic switch with say a 10pF load can reach 64% in 250 ps but a full cycle to from 10 to 90% might be rated somewhere around 1GHz. So reducing the size of the chip and it’s capacitance as well the next stage allows a faster speed.

There are too many other examples to demonstrate so any good book on analog electronics helps to understand how logic circuits are defined in analog terms.